# Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'sBucketH' is being used without being initialized

Tags: c++

I havent long it has not sure why its throwing out runtime errors! i am to allow a user to input diameter and height of a small and large bucket and to calculate the volume between the two buckets if the smaller bucket was placed inside the larger bucket.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Declaring Variables

const double Pi= 3.14;
double lBucketDiameter(0);
double sBucketDiameter(0), sBucketH(0), lBucketH(0);
double volume;
double lBucketVolume, sBucketVolume;
double lBucketRadius;
double sBucketRadius;
    //Output and Input for LARGE BUCKET

cout << "Please enter the Large Buckets Diameter: " << endl;
cin >> lBucketDiameter;

cout << "Please enter the Large Buckets Height: " << endl;
cin >> lBucketH;

//Output and Input for Small Bucket

cout << "Please enter the Small Buckets Diameter: " << endl;
cin >> sBucketDiameter ;

cout << "Please enter the Small Buckets Height: " << endl;
cin >> sBucketH ;

//Formula for Radius

lBucketRadius = lBucketDiameter / 2 ;
sBucketRadius = sBucketDiameter / 2 ;


//Formula for Volume sum for Large and Small Buckets

lBucketVolume = Pi * (lBucketRadius * lBucketRadius) * lBucketH ;

    sBucketVolume = Pi * (sBucketRadius * sBucketRadius) * sBucketH ;

    //Subtracting to find the final answer.

    volume = lBucketVolume - sBucketVolume;

    //Outputting result

    cout << "The volume of space left between the Buckets is: " << volume << "cm3" << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: intialize sBucketH varibale with some value.

Comment: I think there is something wrong in double volume, lBucketRadius = lBucketDiameter / 2, sBucketRadius = sBucketDiameter / 2 ; lBucketDiameter and sBucketDiameter havn't been initialized yet by then

Answer (score 1):

The warning is absolutely correct.

You need to process the values *after* you have input. Right now, you calculate with random values before the user even entered his input. That way, you will get garbage as result.

Move your calculations after your user input.

Comment: @KieranRichards As much as I would like to send an army of dwarves through the cable to magically fix the code you wrote, they are out partying and we have to rely on the old method of "you post your current code" and "I post a solution to the problem". Please post your updated code.

Comment: `lBucketRadius = lBucketDiameter / 2` this line still works on hot air, as `lBucketDiameter` has no value yet. Move the calculation to somewhere, where the value is already set.

Comment: You sir i dont know what you did but i saw my mistake and for this you are honored! Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Put your entire calculation code i.e. the formula after taking the inputs from the user.. and the simplest way to do is to initialize it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just as I was going through trying to sort out some other issues and came across your code. It seemed to me to be absolutely free of error so thought of checking it on Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition IDE.
Lo and behold.. The worked fine as it is shown above (Only copied and pasted the code in a C++ environment in VS) with all the inputs being provided to compute the  volume as you needed.

Comment: Suggest install the above VS environment free from this site: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: for setting up the environment correctly for compiling and running C++ on VS 2017, watch this video: https://youtu.be/WorTYNFNV8Q

Comment: If you have additional information, it would be better to _edit_ your answer and include it there (instead of adding comments about it). [thx]

Comment: Hi elbrant, I tried to do just that but was prevented from doing further edits with a warning message saying that I could do it within 5 minutes of answering . Hence additional comments. Do you have any questions please?